# Why do we add 1 to the count when counting something?

Tags: c++, function, loops, if-statement, boolean

I was wondering, why did we use `count++` instead of, for example `count += 0`, to count the number of even numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            count += 0;  // why it will give me only 1? as output
        else
            continue;
    }
    cout << "num of even: " << count << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well if you add 0 multiple times to a number you don't get anywhere..

Comment: 1 + 0 == 1. What output are you expecting from that?

Comment: Did you mean `count += 1` ?

Comment: In c++ we use ++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> count += 0; // why it will give me only 1? as output

`count += 0` is equivalent to `count = count + 0`. You're not adding anything by adding 0. So your variable stays at 1.

> why did we use count++ instead

`count++` differs from `count += 0`. It increments `count` by **1** and is equivalent to `count += 1`.

At least, with `count++`, you're "acknowledging that `i` is an even number" and therefore counting it. (Behind this is a whole land regarding context and language, which I prefer to not get into.)

Note that, there may be a huge difference between adding 0 and 1 if you were to iterate over a large list of items.

Comment: your are very helpful ! thanks

Answer (score 4):

We add `1` to the `count`, because that is how you count. You start at `0`, and when you find something to count you add `1` to it.

Example:

```
Things to count:
      thing       thing thing             thing       thing

Counting:
      add 1       add 1 add 1             add 1       add 1
zero  one   one   two   three three three four  four  five
```

There are five things.

Because counting is something programmers do a lot, the people who made C++ (actually the people who made C, on which C++ is based) decided that you could write `count++` to mean `count += 1` (which means `count = count + 1`), but it's the same principle.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that `count++` has the same effect as `count+=1`. If you use `count+=0`, `count` won't change (it's the same as `count=count+0`).